# Python Selenium- Print text from a list inside an element that updates on scroll in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, css, selenium

I am using Selenium and Python to grab a list of company names inside a drop-down menu on a page updated with javascript. I am able to click the nav button to make the list of company names visible and can also print the text of the first 50 or so rows.

The `<div class="grid-canvas">` child elements update asynchronously when scrolling through the list. I have not been able to figure out how to grab the text of the Exhibitor Column for the company names that update on the scroll.

What is the best way to handle this problem?

```
driver.get('https://www.expocad.com/host/fx/afassanoco/18csm/exfx.html')
    try:
       element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "nav-btn")))
       if element:
           driver.find_element_by_class_name('nav-btn').click() 
    finally:
       table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "exhGrid")))
       if table:
           print(driver.find_element_by_class_name('slick-viewport').text)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Selenium is overkill for this task. You can simply download XML file:
https://www.expocad.com/host/fx/afassanoco/18csm/fxdata.aspx?FileName=18csm.xml

And parse it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("18csm.xml")

for selem in tree.getroot().iter('S'):
    company_no = None
    company_name = []
    for telem in selem.iter('T'):
        if company_no == None:
            company_no = telem.attrib['v']
        else:
            company_name.append(telem.attrib['v'])
    if company_name != []:
        print(company_no, " ".join(company_name))
```

Comment: Thanks- never thought about taking that approach. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the element and trigger a scroll event via Javascript. Wait for the other names to load, and then you should be able to read them in the same way you read the first 50:

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('SOME_SELECTOR').scrollDown += 100");
```

Not sure if you need to scroll through the grid-canvas or the slick-viewport, but you should find some selector that lets you get a scroll event in. If that doesn't work, you can also try either

```
driver.execute_script('scrollBy(0, 250)')
```

or sending the `Keys.ARROW_DOWN` event

Either way, you can keep that up until you reach the bottom of the list.